# Scrapy.Spider: callback in overrided start_requests does not jump to another custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have the following code:

```
class CustomSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    # Some __init__ definitions

    def start_requests(self):
        for url, args in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_first_page, cb_kwargs=args)

    def parse_first_page(self, response, **kwargs):
        # do the 'first page' stuff
        # This does not jump to the 'parse' method
        self.parse(response, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        # do the parsing like on every page
        next_url = response.css('.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_url is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs=self.args)
```

As you can see, the `CustomSpider` class overrides the `start_requests` which is a generator of the `scrapy.Request`. The code jumps into `parse_first_page` method, but it **fails** to jump to `parse` method. If I pass the `parse` method directly as the callback in `start_requests`, the code runs as expected.

I also tried to debug it, but it simply does not jump to the `parse` method. Is there anything obvious that I am missing here?

Comment: Is there an exception in the logs?

Comment: No, it says: ```2020-05-18 12:41:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)```. There is literally no exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because you are just calling **parse** from **parse_first_page** and doing nothing with the result. You actually need to yield the results as well. The following snippet should work in your case.

```py
def parse_first_page(self, response, **kwargs):
    # do the 'first page' stuff
    for request in self.parse(response, **kwargs):
        yield request
```

Comment: Yes, that's similar to a solution which I figured out later